# Excel multiply field by another column during key in

Tags: excel, vba

I have a `B` column which have many rows of record and by default are empty. Now I would like it if someone keys in any integer into the record lets say on cell `B1`, it should compute  as

```
integer value of cell * (-20)
```

The -20 modifier is stored in lets say `Z1`. Any value keyed in in B1,B12... Bn should computed the same way as above. How can I do this ?

**EDIT**

Excpected result

[image]

Comment: This is possible using events. Are you somehow familiar with macro or somewhat inclined to it? If not, then I can't think of a work around without vba.

Comment: I am not familiar but I am keen to learn :)

Comment: Then try what Arich posted :) it should do the trick.

Comment: The question has pushed people to respond with VBA code because of the specification that the cell modified by the user should be the very same one over-written with another value. Maybe there is a need for the spreadsheet to act that way but the user experience is likely to be very frustrating. Can you imagine working with a spreadsheet in which the values you type into a cell don't stick but are over-written as soon as you press Enter? Is it not possible/preferable to set up the spreadsheet so that the user enters a value in col B and the value multiplied by Z1 appears next to it in Col C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the `Change` event, but you need to take a few things into account:

1. What if the user pastes several values?
2. What if the user enters a formula?
3. What if the user deletes some data?

---

This version takes these things into account

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set rng = Intersect(Me.Columns(2), Target)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each cl In rng.Cells
            If Not IsEmpty(cl) Then
                If Not cl.HasFormula Then
                    cl.Value = cl.Value * Me.Range("Z1")
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @chris neilsen although all scenarios were seemed covered, i think an error handler is still valuable since you are turning events on and off :)

Comment: @L42 Error handling is (almost) always advisable :) I don't see why turning Events off would affect that?  And I just thought of another potential issue: what is the user enters non-numeric data?

Comment: @chrisneilsen ah, cause if error occured somewhere, event will not be turned back on again. :) See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519451/auto-get-value-in-excel-vba/21520211#21520211). Well just a thought. :D

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`Change` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) for this. Paste this into the [Sheet module](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/codemods.htm) of the sheet you want to use this on:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
    Target = Target.Value * Range("Z1")
End If

End Sub
```

The `Intersect` method tests to make sure the changed cell is in Column `B`. `Target` is the cell whose value was changed.

Comment: I am very new to this, where do I open the Sheet module ?

Comment: See my edited answer for a link about modules. Use `Alt` + `F11` to open the VBEditor, then locate the sheet in the project explorer on the left (`Ctrl` + `R` if it isn't visible) and double click your sheet name to open it.